# Best data structure for version control

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I've a dynamic array of 10^7 512-bit elements in which elements can be added, deleted and interchanged with each other. Every time, a user manipulates the array, I want to record the changes in a space-efficient way such that I'm able to get the final version without needing to evaluate all the previous versions. Which is the best data structure for doing that?

An expensive  way is to store all the versions of the array:

```
[1,5,7,3,8,2]
[1,4,5,7,3,8,2]
[1,5,4,7,3,8,2]
[1,4,5,3,7,8,2]
[2,4,5,3,7,8,1]
```

Another way (this would require to compute every version to find the current state):

```
[1,5,7,3,8,2]
Add 4 between 1 and 5
Switch 4 with 5
Switch 3 with 7
Switch 1 with 2
```

Is there an space-efficient alternative that solves the problem?!
Thank You!

Comment: concatenated hashes

Comment: can you help me out?

Comment: which language is it. your tags span everything. platform matters too...

Comment: my language is python

Comment: If your language is Python, do not add JavaScript or C++ tags too.  You will attract down-votes (negative attention) rather than gain a benefit from adding the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Consider storing only the most recent version in full and then calculate backward deltas to prior versions.  If you normally only need the latest version, this gives good performance.  If you normally need the oldest version, store the oldest version and the forward deltas.  As to what the delta format should be, it depends on how big the changes are in a given 512-bit (64-byte) block.  At worst, you might include ranges of blocks that have changed, with the old or new version specified (depending on backward or forward deltas).  Or you might record changes in portions of blocks.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathon for the answer. there are no changes in the 512-bit blocks per se. elements are only added/deleted or rearranged. No data change happens inside the element. Also my original question was what data structure should I use to store the 'backward deltas' efficiently? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ?

Answer (score 0):

try to save your data in text file (that is have linefeed at end).

and using git/svn (any SCM system) to tracking the version changes.

if you are able to split you huge data into multiple small chunk of data with meaningful fileanme,  you will find git/svn will help you lot.